# Hours, Date, Day Count Calculation

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataset, python-datetime

I have this huge dataset which has dates for several days and timestamps. The datetime format is in UNIX format. The datasets are logs of some login.

The code is supposed to group start and end time logs and provide log counts and unique id counts.

I am trying to get some stats like:

```
total log counts per hour & unique login ids per hour.
```

log count with choice of hours i.e. `24hrs, 12hrs, 6 hrs, 1 hr, etc` and `day` of the week and such options.

I am able to split the data with `start` and `end` hours but I am not able to get the stats of counts of `logs` and `unique ids`.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime,time

# This splits data from start to end time 
start = time(8,0,0)
end =   time(20,0,0)

    with open('input', 'r') as infile, open('output','w') as outfile:
        for row in infile:
            col = row.split()
            t1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(col[2])).time()
            t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(col[3])).time()
            print (t1 >= start and t2 <= end)
```

Input data format: The data has no headers but the fields are given below. The number of days is not known in input.

```
UserID, StartTime, StopTime, GPS1, GPS2
00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022d9064bc,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
00904b4557d3,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
00022de73863,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
00904b14b494,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
00022d1406df,1073260807,1073260809,820428,438735
00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022dba8f51,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022de1c6c1,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
003065f30f37,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00904b48a3b6,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00904b83a0ea,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
00904b85d3cf,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
00904b99499c,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
00904bb96e83,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525
00904bf91b75,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525
```

Expected Output: Example Output

```
StartTime, EndTime, Day, LogCount, UniqueIDCount

00:00:00, 01:00:00, Mon, 349, 30  

StartTime and Endtime = Human readable format
```

Only to separate data with range of time is already achieved, but I am trying to write a round off time and calculate the counts of logs and uniqueids. Solution with `Pandas` is also welcome.

Edit One: I more details

```
StartTime         --> EndTIime
1/5/2004, 5:30:01 --> 1/5/2004, 5:30:03
```

But that falls between `5:00:00 --> 6:00:00` . So this way count of all the logs in the time range is what I am trying to find. Similarly for others also like

```
5:00:00 --> 6:00:00 Hourly Count 
00:00:00 --> 6:00:00 Every 6 hours 
00:00:00 --> 12:00:00 Every 12 hours 

5 Jan 2004, Mon --> count 
6 Jan 2004, Tue --> Count
```

And so on Looking for a generic program where I can change the time/hours range as needed.

Comment: what are the minimum and maximum dates/time do you want to have in your report? Is it from min(StartTime) to max(EndTime) rounded to hours or something else?

Comment: @MaxU I have couple of data sets some are for 100 days and some are for years. Cannot confined to only one data set and the size of data sets is more than 1GB. The time runs 24 hrs. I need to separate them in chunks of hours and get the log count in those days

Comment: can you post or upload somewhere bit more data, because currently there is only one hour of data?

Comment: @MaxU Please find the small chunk of the full data https://www.dropbox.com/s/varv1lyb5uskexh/dart_small.csv?dl=0

Comment: How many times do you want to count rows like that: `2004-01-05 00:00:10 -->  2004-01-05 04:19:06`? 5 times ?

Comment: @MaxU Made an Edit in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately i couldn't find any elegant solution.

Here is my attempt:

```
fn = r'D:\temp\.data\dart_small.csv'
cols = ['UserID','StartTime','StopTime','GPS1','GPS2']
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime

# 'start' and 'end' for the reporting DF: `r`
# which will contain equal intervals (1 hour in this case)
start = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime.min(), unit='s').date()
end = pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime.max(), unit='s').date() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# building reporting DF: `r`
freq = '1H'  # 1 Hour frequency
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
r['start'] = (r.index - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds().astype(np.int64)

# 1 hour in seconds, minus one second (so that we will not count it twice)
interval = 60*60 - 1

r['LogCount'] = 0
r['UniqueIDCount'] = 0


for i, row in r.iterrows():
        # intervals overlap test
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test
        # i've slightly simplified the calculations of m and d
        # by getting rid of division by 2,
        # because it can be done eliminating common terms
    u = df[np.abs(df.m - 2*row.start - interval) < df.d + interval].UserID
    r.ix[i, ['LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount']] = [len(u), u.nunique()]

r['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.weekday_name.str[:3]
r['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.time
r['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start + interval + 1, unit='s').dt.time

print(r[r.LogCount > 0])
```

PS the less periods you will have in the *report* DF - `r`, the faster it will count. So you may want to get rid of rows (times) if you know beforehand that those timeframes won't contain any data (for example during the weekends, holidays, etc.)

Result:

```
                          start  LogCount  UniqueIDCount  Day StartTime   EndTime
2004-01-05 00:00:00  1073260800        24             15  Mon  00:00:00  01:00:00
2004-01-05 01:00:00  1073264400         5              5  Mon  01:00:00  02:00:00
2004-01-05 02:00:00  1073268000         3              3  Mon  02:00:00  03:00:00
2004-01-05 03:00:00  1073271600         3              3  Mon  03:00:00  04:00:00
2004-01-05 04:00:00  1073275200         2              2  Mon  04:00:00  05:00:00
2004-01-06 12:00:00  1073390400        22             12  Tue  12:00:00  13:00:00
2004-01-06 13:00:00  1073394000         3              2  Tue  13:00:00  14:00:00
2004-01-06 14:00:00  1073397600         3              2  Tue  14:00:00  15:00:00
2004-01-06 15:00:00  1073401200         3              2  Tue  15:00:00  16:00:00
2004-01-10 16:00:00  1073750400        20             11  Sat  16:00:00  17:00:00
2004-01-14 23:00:00  1074121200       218             69  Wed  23:00:00  00:00:00
2004-01-15 00:00:00  1074124800        12             11  Thu  00:00:00  01:00:00
2004-01-15 01:00:00  1074128400         1              1  Thu  01:00:00  02:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is really great.. Let me execute with full data and I will reply back soon.

Comment: I do not have luxury of eliminating holiday or weekends. I have to count every day.

Comment: Firstly Thanks a bunch for the solution.. Is it not possible to write `Day` as `Mon,Tue, etc` ? And Can you point me where I need to change for time frequency. This is for 1 hour but When I need to check for 6hrs or 12 hrs ? Or is possible to also include the module of start time and end time i.e. switch between the `hourly` and `choice of time series` like I wrote in above program? These bunch doubts yet to be solved.

Comment: `File "time_split.py", line 6, in <module>
    df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'StopTime'`

Comment: @SitzBlogz, for the `Day` column you can use `.dt.weekday_name` or if you need just the first tree letters: `.dt.weekday_name[:3]` instead of `.dt.dayofweek`. For the frequency you need to adjust two variables: `freq` and `interval`.

Comment: @SitzBlogz, `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'StopTime'` - is pretty self-explanatory, so i don't think i can add something more meaningful here... ;)

Comment: Yes but the data has both the start and stop time columns. The same dataset but the full version in GB size. And the original dataset has no header and no index

Comment: You can specify the column names, when reading your CSV, using `names` parameter of `read_csv()` function or afterwards: `df.columns = ['first_col','second_col', etc.]`

Comment: Please could you help by editing the code clearly .. it will be huge finishing help for me .. and the place where i can change the hours

Comment: Thank you so much for bring it to this far.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It was huge help. :) :)

Comment: @SitzBlogz, glad i could help. You may also want to check this [technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38203511/5741205) - it's bit tricky, but it seems to be very efficient

Comment: It is tricky .. I feel your solution only difficult as I am not good with programming .. I am more into research and analysis and zero with development (I am in process improve myself with programing)

Comment: May I request for a small edit with the code. I want to put one column with `Date` which is in the data-set. How do I Put that ?

Comment: @SitzBlogz, do you mean the same `Date` column as in the index?

Comment: I got it `r['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.date` and this worked very well