# Efficiently check if value is present in any of given ranges

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrame objects:

- `A` contains `'start'` and `'finish'` columns
- `B` has column `'date'`

The goal is to efficiently create a boolean mask indicating if `date` is in `[start, finish]` interval

Naive iterating taking too much time, I guess there is a method to do that  faster

UPDATE:
`A` and `B` have **different number of rows**

UPDATE2: 
Sample:

```
A
    | start     | finish    |
    |-------    |--------   |
    | 1         | 3         |
    | 50        | 83        |
    | 30        | 42        |

B
    | date      | 
    |-------    |
    | 31        | 
    | 20        | 
    | 2.5       |
    | 84        |
    | 1000      |

Output:
            | in_interval | 
            |-------    |
            | True      | 
            | False     | 
            | True      |
            | False     |
            | False     |
```

P.S. I have my data in datetime format but I guess that the solution will not differ from one for numbers

Comment: so you're asking for `df[(df['date'] > df['start']) & (df['date'] < df['finish'])]`?

Comment: Do you want to do it element wise (ie you need dataframes of same size)?

Comment: no, these are two separate dataframes with different number of rows so this one will not work I think

Comment: So, if A has M rows and B has N rows, the output will have NxM rows?

Comment: Provided sample output with numbers instead of datetime for simplicity

Comment: @GuillaumeThomas check out my sample output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a O(n) complexity. The idea is to transform the representation. In A, you store one row per interval. I would suggest a dataframe which stores one row per transition (ie entering an interval, leaving an interval).

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'start': [1, 50, 30],
        'finish': [3, 83, 42]    
    }
)

starts = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': 1}, index=A.start.tolist())
finishs = pd.DataFrame(data={'finish': -1}, index=A.finish.tolist())
transitions = pd.merge(starts, finishs, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)
transitions

    start  finish
1       1       0
3       0      -1
30      1       0
42      0      -1
50      1       0
83      0      -1
```

this dataframe stores per date the type of transitions. Now, we need to know at each date if we are in an interval or not. It looks like counting the opening & closing parenthesis. You can do:

```
transitions['transition'] = (transitions.pop('finish') + transitions.pop('start')).cumsum()
transitions

    transition
1            1
3            0
30           1
42           0
50           1
83           0
```

Here it says:

- At 1, i'm in an interval
- At 3, i'm not
- In general, if the value is strictly greater than 0, it's in an interval.
- Note that this handles overlapping interval

And now you merge with your B dataframe:

```
B = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[31, 20, 2.5, 84, 1000]
)

pd.merge(transitions, B, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(method='ffill').loc[B.index].astype(bool)

       transition
31.0         True
20.0        False
2.5          True
84.0        False
1000.0      False
```

Comment: I really like your solution! Is there a way to consider `finish` as a closed interval bound? I.e. if we add value `83` to `B` - it won't be considered as belonging to the `[50, 83]` range - do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Yes, in the first merge the index is sorted in the ascendant order. apply the same logic with a descendant order. At the end, you have one transition for closed-opened intervals and one transition for opened-closed intervals. closed-closed means "either of them".

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want the output to be `True` if there is at least one interval in which the date is?

Is an `apply(lambda)` efficient enough for you? (It might be a little long for a big dataframe as it iterates over the rows of `B`). If it is, you can try this:

```
def in_range(date,start,finish):
    return (True in ((start < date) & (date < finish)).unique())

B.date.apply(lambda x: in_range(x,A.start,A.finish))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
```

EDIT: MaxU's answer works better in fact. Here are the timers for 10 000 rows dataframes (A and B):

```
%timeit B2.date.apply(lambda x: in_range(x,A2.start,A2.finish))
1 loop, best of 3: 9.82 s per loop

%timeit B2.date.apply(lambda x: ((x >= A2.start) & (x <= A2.finish)).any())
1 loop, best of 3: 7.31 s per loop
```

Comment: i think you can simplify it a little bit: `B.date.apply(lambda x: ((x >= a.start) & (x <= a.finish)).any())`

Comment: Thank you, I've used this approach, that is taking too much time at my 100mb dataset